# Jenkins - Email attachment with dynamic html report files

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am using Editable Email Notification in Jenkins. How do we get dynamic(report file name changed in work-space after every build) .Pdf files attached in e-mail from work-space.

Example: `Root/TestResults/*.pdf`

Above will give all pdf attachments

Example: `Root/TestResults/Final_Report_2015_11_07_06_47.pdf`

Above path is giving same file when exist.

But file name is getting changed dynamically, i.e. `Final_Report_XXXX_XX_XX_XX_XX.pdf.`

Is there any way to get latest file based one dynamic report file name check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Filesystem List Parameter' Plug-in in Jenkins, which can be useful for your question. refer to link for reference

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Filesystem+List+Parameter+Plug-in

you can sort and send the first one

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but not able to figure out how to include this file in email notification. I've added Filesystem List Parameter but how to include that file in email?